# Where to find HTML pages in Cordova based android application

Tags: android, cordova, hybrid

I am working on a **Hybrid** Android application. Now i want to access my HTML pages in android.Actually i want to open some particular page from Android Code based on some events.
So there is any or **plug-in** by using which i can open  these in my Android code.Please show me some way ASAP.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do u know how to create basic app using phonegap? ie Cardova?

Comment: OfCourse but the problem is to call that pages form andorid i.e Java code

Comment: The HTML pages are stored inside the ASSET folder, if that's what you mean

Comment: check my answer @AnujSharma

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect your HTML, CSS, JavaScript file in Unsigned and Debug version of your application. So, normally you'll be not able to Inspect the code of Signed Production version of a App.

To inspect the HTML/CSS/Javscript code of your application, your application must run Webview.

**Steps -**

1) Install the App on Phone, connect the Phone with PC with Developer Mode enabled.

2) Open Chrome, chrome://inspect , goto devices
At the top you can see the model name of your Android device followed by its serial number.
If there are any running apps using WebView, you’ll see a heading for each app.

To open up DevTools on your development machine and inspect or debug the live content on your Android device, click the Inspect button next to the tab that you want to investigate. A new instance of DevTools opens up on your development machine.

**Step by Step Guide**

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the Help but actually i want to open a page from java code.So how to do that

Comment: You want show HTML as browser shows? then use Android Webview - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_webview_layout.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can access HTML files  in `/assets/www` folder, You can load it to java through `loadUrl();`

Example:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        loadUrl(launchUrl);
    } }
```

Example app link: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-sample-hybrid-android

Full docs: http://docs.phonegap.com/tutorials/develop/1-embed-webview/android/

Comment: Thanks for reply
But this works when we want to change the first page.But mine requirement is to call for eg. login page in middle of application.

Comment: are you creating hybrid or native app? please explain some scenario, so that i can suggest some thing useful @AnujSharma